# "Some" and "Any"; countables and uncountable

Tags: determiners, uncountable-nouns, countability, some-vs-any

I'm doing my English homework and my book says these sentences are correct:

1) Do you have any wine?

2) Can I have some water, please?

My questions are:

- These sentences are structured differently.  Does a difference between "wine" and "water" cause the sentences to be structured differently?
- Why do we not use the word "some" in sentence #1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Both *some* and *any* are used with indefinite reference.
>
> *Some* is used if the idea is *restricted* or *limited* in some way.
>   *Any* is used if the idea is *unrestricted* or *unlimited*.
>   *Any* applies to all or none; *some* applies to part.
>
> The restriction may be a real one - *There's some cheese in the fridge* - or a psychological one, existing only in the mind of the speaker - *Would you like something to eat?*

Michael Lewis (1986.34), *The English Verb*, LTP: Hove.

> Do you have **any** wine/water? - Unrestricted
>
> Can I have **some** wine/water, please? - Restricted, a limited amount

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference between 'information questions', and requests or suggestions. If you ask an information question, you want the person listening just to give you some information:

- Is there **any** bread?
- Are there **any** doctors on the plane?
- Do **any** animals lay eggs but give their babies milk?

If you want to make an offer or suggestion, or you want to ask someone to do something, you aren't really asking for information:

- Could I have **some** water?
- Please can we take **some** photos?
- May we bring **some** friends?
- Shall I ask **some**one?
- Shall I cook **some** pizza?
- Why don't you ask **some**one?
- How about we take **some** time off?

Although these examples look like questions, they are not really about getting information. They are a way of telling our listener that we want them to do something (for example, give us water, give us permission) - or they are a way of offering to do something (to ask somebody, to cook some pizza) or suggesting something to the listener (that they ask someone, or have some time off).

It isn't really possible to use ideas about restricted or unqualified amounts with questions in the same way that it is with normal declarative affirmative sentences.

A general, useful, rule of thumb which will stop you making very many mistakes is:

- use *any* for information questions
- use *some* for requests, offers and suggestions:

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

In these examples, "wine" and "water" are analogous.  If the conversation happened at Cana *circa* 30 A.D., a guest could substitute "wine" for "water" in either sentence.  (Of course, it would be about as miraculous for people in 30 A.D. to be speaking modern English, as for a guest to change water into wine.)

All six of the following sentences are correct.  #5 and #6 do not sound as natural to my (American) ear as #1 and #3.

1. Do you have any wine?
2. Can I have some water, please?
3. Do you have any water?
4. Can I have some wine, please?
5. Do you have some wine?
6. Do you have some water?

In all six of the above examples, "wine" and "water" are used as uncountable nouns.  The above examples assume that either there is one kind of wine or water, or that the requester does not care what kind of wine or water they might be given.  As uncountable nouns, the way to pluralize the amount of "wine" or "water" is to explicitly pluralize a measurable unit of each noun.  For example:

- "a glass of water" or "two glasses of water"
- "an ounce of wine" or "two ounces of wine"

"Wine" and "water" can also be used as countable nouns.  In the examples below, the requester is asking about **types** of wines and waters, not **volumes** of indistinguishable wine or water.  #11 and #12 do not sound as natural to my (American) ear as #7 and #9.

7. Do you have any wines?
8. Can I have some waters, please?
9. Do you have any waters?
10. Can I have some wines, please?
11. Do you have some wines?
12. Do you have some waters?

For example, the "wines" might be a *Champagne* and a Merlot.  The waters might be Perrier and tap water.