Check if anything/something is wrong with the cable

Yuki: For some reason, I couldn't charge my iPad.
Reiko: I think you need to check if anything/something is wrong
with the cable.

Which is correct, anything or something?
[Edit] Lambie's suggested thread is about wine-vs-water, and sentences #1 and #2 are completely different in structure and function. It adds to my confusion because the sentences being discussed are interrogative ones.
In "Can I have some wine/water, please?", "some" is being used because the speaker expects the answer "yes". This is what I learned in school.

In this context, both are correct and mean (essentially) the same.

Why don't you show some research? We aren't an editing service...

@Lambie What do you mean by "Why don't you show some research?"?

I mean we ask people to show they have made an effort on this own and show what that effort is. Also, these kinds of questions very often have already been answered.

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38030/some-and-any-countables-and-uncountable from way back in 2014. :)

This question is similar to: "Some" and "Any"; countables and uncountable. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@James K. I didn't think both were correct. I asked the same question to my acquaintances who are more competent in English, but their opinions differed. Thank you very much, James K.

@Lambie I don't understand at all how on earth your suggested thread could answer my question.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

No, some and any, somebody and anybody, something and anything are all the same in terms of restricted and unrestricted as given in that link. That's the point and the one not explained in the first comment.

In if-clauses "any" has the same meaning as in questions.

In such a context, though both options work,  "anything" is more suitable.
Explanation:

Use "anything" when you're unsure if there is an issue.
Use  "something" when you suspect there is a specific issue, but you're not sure what it is.

In this case, Reiko's sentence starts with "I think," which indicates uncertainty, so "anything" is the better choice.
